# How to get minimum and maximum value of matlab imcontrast tool?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I am building an image analysis GUI in matlab where at one point, the contrast of the image can be modified using the `imcontrast` tool. Next, I want to automatically apply this contrast setting to other images, which is possible with `imshow(image, [min_value max_value])`. Therefore, I would like to return my program to return these `min_value` and `max_value` from the `imcontrast` tool (see picture below). Any suggestions how I can get these values automatically?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `figure` handle returned by `imcontrast` to find the uicontrols that contain the Window limits. You can retrieve the edit box handles using the `Tag` names, retrieve the `String` property and convert it to a number using `str2double`.

```
hfig = imcontrast(gca);
window_min = str2double(get(findobj(hfig, 'tag', 'window min edit'), 'String'));
window_max = str2double(get(findobj(hfig, 'tag', 'window max edit'), 'String'));
```

As a side note, the way that I discovered the tag names was using the following where in 2014b+ you see the tag name in parentheses:

```
findobj(hfig, 'style', 'edit')

%   UIControl    (max data range edit)
%   UIControl    (min data range edit)
%   UIControl    (outlier percent edit)
%   UIControl    (window center edit)
%   UIControl    (window width edit)
%   UIControl    (window max edit)
%   UIControl    (window min edit)
```

It appears that the tag names have not changed since at least R2008a so.

**Update**

If you want to get the value when closed, you can use the `CloseRequestFcn` callback of the figure to call a custom function to retrieve these values.

```
set(hfig, 'CloseRequestFcn', @(s,e)getValues(s))

function getValues(hfig)
    window_min = str2double(get(findobj(hfig, 'tag', 'window min edit'), 'String'));
    window_max = str2double(get(findobj(hfig, 'tag', 'window max edit'), 'String'));
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! However, these values do not get updated when I manually change the limits in the tool. So I need to know the values when the figure gets closed. Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: I now just inserted a `while` loop which checks every 0.01 sec if the handle to the `imcontrast` tool still exists and updates the values. Probably there are more elegant solutions.

Comment: @sdbonte Updated with an example of how you could intercept the figure closing

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code I have for this:

close all
clear all
I=imread('pout.tif');
imshow(I);

%--------------
ifig = gcf; % Change here
%--------------

hfig_imcontrast = imcontrast(gca);

set(hfig_imcontrast, 'CloseRequestFcn', @(s,e)getValues(s))
%--------------
set(ifig, 'CloseRequestFcn', @(s,e)closeFig(s,hfig_imcontrast)) % Change here

findall(hfig_imcontrast)
uiwait(hfig_imcontrast)

window_min
window_max

I_bit_depth = class(I);
I_colormap = gray(double(intmax(I_bit_depth)));
imshow(imadjust(I,[I_colormap(window_min);I_colormap(window_max)],[]));

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function closeFig(hfig,ifig)
close(ifig);
close(hfig);
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function getValues(hfig)
    window_min = str2double(get(findobj(hfig, 'tag', 'window min edit'), 'String'));
    window_max = str2double(get(findobj(hfig, 'tag', 'window max edit'), 'String'));

    assignin('base', 'window_min', window_min);
    assignin('base', 'window_max', window_max);
end
```